# how to compile scss files in my part folder?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I want to compile all the scss to css in my part folder . how to do it ?
the compass watch command can only compile the root sass folder to css folder.
for example: I want to compile top_menu.scss to top_menu.css.

```
config.rb
sass
css
part
    top_menu
    |--top_menu.php
    |--sass
    |  |--top_menu.scss
    |--css
    |   |--top_menu.css
```

Comment: Is there a practical purpose for having a sass directory *and* Sass files that need to be compiled that live outside of that directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this executing the **compass watch** command as it follows

```
compass watch --sass-dir part/top_menu/sass --css-dir part/top_menu/css -c config.rb
```

I hope it helps.

Cheers!

Comment: But will this command also compile the contents of the `sass/` folder?

Comment: Yes it will, check out compass --help for further details @lolmaus :-)

Compass has a ton of flags you can use to tweak its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `part` folder inside the `sass` folder and set `config.rb` to watch the `sass` folder:

```
sass_dir = 'sass'
```

UPD1: if you want to keep the structure, try pointing `sass_dir` at the root folder. Another option is to make those files partials that would embed into one big css file instead of multiple smaller ones.

Comment: no, I want to keep the structure , your method will only compile the scss in folder css/part/top_menu/top_menu.css ,not created sass/part/top_menu/top_menu.css

Comment: What's the same? And what structure would you like to have in your CSS folder? You won't receive any help here unless you provide as much details as possible. We're not telepaths.

Comment: plugins in the part folder can be used for other project ,it should alway has css folder and scss folder , then when it is moved to other place ,we are clear that we can recreate the css from this plugin scss. your method can only create the css file finally in css/part/xxx/css/xxx.css , not in real in the sass/part/xxx/css/xxx.css.